# Changing from extended desktop to mirrored desktop on multiple monitors in Vista

Tags: windows-vista

Is there an easy way to change a laptop's external monitor (projector) from an extended desktop to a mirrored desktop in Windows Vista?  On the current laptop we're trying it on, when we uncheck the "Extend my desktop to this monitor" box, the projector just stops displaying anything.

One workaround is to go into the NVidia control panel and switch it, or to click the Add Projector button in the Vista mobility center, but neither of these are quick or natural.  It'd be nice if there was a way from the display settings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe nVidia's nView tool would allow you to do this with a keyboard shortcut. Unfortunately, nVidia has decided not to release nView for Windows Vista.

MultiMon (Free and Pro versions available) or UltraMon ($40 - trial version available) may be helpful. UltraMon in particular is very flexible and includes hotkey/scripting support.

Some notebooks also have function keys available for managing external displays.